# What logic needs to be changed to get the star pattern

Tags: java, ascii-art

```
class Starr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int res;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                res=i+j;
                if(res>=6) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Expected:

```
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

To get the above expected result i made the following changes,

```
  {
    System.out.print(" *"); /* Added a space before '*' */
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.print("  "); /* Added 2 spaces */
  }
```

I would like to know if this expected result can be achieved in another logic where i don't have to change the print statement. Whatever changes i have done is a right approach?

Comment: Considering that the spacing between asterisks is controlled somewhat by the println statement...I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: Why would you want to do it any other way? The solution is the simplest possible and works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve a way of printing whitespaces between the stars without printing anything, although you can achieve the desired output without using whitespaces. This could be done with System.out.format() or System.out.printf(). format and printf are actually the same thing in practice. For you particularly:

```
System.out.printf("%2s", "*");
```

This means that this output should print two characters, out of which the first one should be '*'. The rest will be whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, It works!

```java
int res;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        res = i + j;
        String sp = (j != 1) ? " " : "";
        if (res >= 6) {
            System.out.print(sp + "*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(sp + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
        *
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class StarPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This loop print the number of * rows
        for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
            // This prints the empty space instead of *
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            // Print the * in the desired position
            for (int k = 5; k >= i; k--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            // Move the caret to the next line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Comment: Make a little explanation of your code so other users can understand it easier